Error al accesar a una página en oracle apex
Tengo el siguiente problema en oracle apex y es que no logro acessar al el modo de desarrollo de la página. Esta página se copio de una aplicación a otra pero cuando quiero editar algunos aspectos para poder hacer que funcione pero se queda cargando asi.


suele pasar cuando tienes referencia a tablas procedure o funciones o plugins que no estan instalando en el workspace actual o el usuario no tiene los permisos!

Gracias por la información. El problema era justo o de los Plug-Ins. Al copiar todos los de la otra aplicación funciono y me dejo editarla.
